# End to end testing implementation for Visual Studio Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, e2e-testing, vscode-extensions

I have developed a Visual Studio code extension. i want to implement end to end testing for each Command we configure in package.json. these commands have Quickpicks etc

i am not sure how to implement tests

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a concrete solution to do the same. While googling, I came across [this](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester). I haven't tried it yet but looks promising to me. Please share your experience in case you use it. Also, don't forget to share if you find a better working solution for the same.